# Lark parser parsing input in wrong order

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, lark-parser

So I'm making a programming language in python using lark, and when I parse an input such as

```
print("HI");
x = input("Number: ");
```

It parses the `input` statement before the `print` statement. Below is somewhat what my code looks like.

```py
from lark import Lark, Transformer, v_args
from lark.indenter import Indenter
grammar = '''
?start: expr
      | statement* -> statement
?statement: "print" "(" expr ")" ";"  -> print_statement
          | "input" "(" expr ")" ";"  -> input_statement
          | NAME "=" "input" "(" expr ")" ";" -> var_input_statement
          | NAME "=" expr ";"      -> assign_var
?expr: STRING            -> string
     | NUMBER            -> number
     | NUMBER "+" NUMBER -> add
     | NUMBER "-" NUMBER -> sub
     | NUMBER "*" NUMBER -> mul
     | NUMBER "/" NUMBER -> div
     | STRING "+" STRING -> str_add
     | NAME              -> get_var

%import common.ESCAPED_STRING -> STRING 
%import common.NUMBER
%import common.CNAME -> NAME
%declare _INDENT _DEDENT
%import common.WS_INLINE
%ignore WS_INLINE
%import common.NEWLINE -> _NL
%ignore _NL
'''


class Print():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def eval(self):
        return print(self.value)


class Input():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def eval(self):
        return input(self.value)


@v_args(inline=True)
class MainTransformer(Transformer):
    number = int
    string = str

    def __init__(self):
        self.vars = {}

    def add(self, val1, val2):
        return int(val1) + int(val2)

    def sub(self, val1, val2):
        return int(val1) - int(val2)

    def mul(self, val1, val2):
        return int(val1) * int(val2)

    def div(self, val1, val2):
        return int(val1) / int(val2)

    def get_var(self, name):
        try:
            return self.vars[name]
        except KeyError:
            raise Exception(f"Variable {name} not found")

    def assign_var(self, name, value):
        if name == "print":
            pass
        if type(value) == str:
            value = value.strip('"')
        self.vars[name] = value

    def var_input_statement(self, name, value):
        data = self.input_statement(value, store_data=True)
        self.assign_var(name, data)

    def print_statement(self, value=" "):
        if type(value) == str:
            value = value.strip('"')
        return Print(value)

    def input_statement(self, value, store_data=False):
        if type(value) == str:
            value = value.strip('"')
        if store_data == True:
            data = input(value)
            return data
        else:
            return Input(value)

    def statement(self, *values):
        for value in values:
            if value == None:
                pass
            else:
                value.eval()


class MainIndenter(Indenter):
    NL_type = '_NL'
    OPEN_PAREN_types = ['LPAR', 'LBRACE']
    CLOSE_PAREN_types = ['RPAR', 'RBRACE']
    INDENT_TYPE = '_INDENT'
    DEDENT_type = '_DEDENT'
    tab_len = 8


parser = Lark(grammar, parser='lalr',
              transformer=MainTransformer(), postlex=MainIndenter())
main_parser = parser.parse

data_input = '''
print("HI");
x = input("Number: ");
'''
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_parser(data_input)
```

This is somewhat the gist of my code, I don't know why my parser isn't parsing in order. Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please post a [mre]. Your code has various minor errors (I guess they are minor) and it doesn't include a lexical specification, so it cannot be tested.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry, I typed this by hand.

Comment: I fixed it, it should work now

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're seeing this behaviour is because of your transformer.

You seem to be partway between evaluating the tree in the Transformer as it is executed (as you do for the var_input_statement, which is why it requests input immediately) and producing output at the end (as you do for print_statement, which is why they appear after the input). You have to choose one or the other.

One alternative is to ignore your Input and Print classes and simply immediately produce output/request input/do calculations - then you'll get them in the sequence you expect, i.e. as per the program code you'r parsing.

The other alternative is to delay everything until the `.eval()` methods are called, in which case your transformer had to emit a sequence of class instances which don't directly evaluate anything - well, you could immediately add two literal numbers together, but for the sake of simplicity I suggest you leave out optimisations until you've got it working unoptimised. This alternative needs more complex changes to your code so it doesn't evaluate e.g. add straightaway - you have to maintain the variables at `.eval()` time, and do the `expr` calculations then too, and update variables with the results. However you haven't yet got the classes need for expressions so you can just call `eval()` on those and they will use the variables.

Here is some very mildly modified code from your mre which takes the first approach - you'll have to work out the complications of the second approach yourself.

Personally I would keep some print statements in the transformer just I can keep track of what's going on, until it's working and stable. Longer-term you might turn those print statements into logging calls.

```
from lark import Lark, Transformer, v_args
from lark.indenter import Indenter
grammar = '''
?start: expr
      | statement* -> statement
?statement: "print" "(" expr ")" ";"  -> print_statement
          | "input" "(" expr ")" ";"  -> input_statement
          | NAME "=" "input" "(" expr ")" ";" -> var_input_statement
          | NAME "=" expr ";"      -> assign_var
?expr: STRING            -> string
     | NUMBER            -> number
     | NUMBER "+" NUMBER -> add
     | NUMBER "-" NUMBER -> sub
     | NUMBER "*" NUMBER -> mul
     | NUMBER "/" NUMBER -> div
     | STRING "+" STRING -> str_add
     | NAME              -> get_var

%import common.ESCAPED_STRING -> STRING 
%import common.NUMBER
%import common.CNAME -> NAME
%declare _INDENT _DEDENT
%import common.WS_INLINE
%ignore WS_INLINE
%import common.NEWLINE -> _NL
%ignore _NL
'''


class Print():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def eval(self):
        return print(self.value)


class Input():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def eval(self):
        return input(self.value)


@v_args(inline=True)
class MainTransformer(Transformer):
    number = int
    string = str

    def __init__(self):
        self.vars = {}

    def add(self, val1, val2):
        return int(val1) + int(val2)

    def sub(self, val1, val2):
        return int(val1) - int(val2)

    def mul(self, val1, val2):
        return int(val1) * int(val2)

    def div(self, val1, val2):
        return int(val1) / int(val2)

    def get_var(self, name):
        try:
            return self.vars[name]
        except KeyError:
            raise Exception(f"Variable {name} not found")

    def assign_var(self, name, value):
        if name == "print":
            pass
        if type(value) == str:
            value = value.strip('"')
        self.vars[name] = value

    def var_input_statement(self, name, value):
        data = self.input_statement(value, store_data=True)
        self.assign_var(name, data)

    def print_statement(self, value=" "):
        if type(value) == str:
            value = value.strip('"')
            print( "PRINTING",value )   # ADDED
        return Print(value)

    def input_statement(self, value, store_data=False):
        if type(value) == str:
            value = value.strip('"')
        if store_data == True:
            data = input(value)
            return data
        else:
            return Input(value) # UNUSED

    def statement(self, *values):
        for value in values:
            if value == None:
                pass
            else:
#                value.eval()   # COMMENTED
                pass           # ADDED


class MainIndenter(Indenter):
    NL_type = '_NL'
    OPEN_PAREN_types = ['LPAR', 'LBRACE']
    CLOSE_PAREN_types = ['RPAR', 'RBRACE']
    INDENT_TYPE = '_INDENT'
    DEDENT_type = '_DEDENT'
    tab_len = 8


parser = Lark(grammar, parser='lalr',
              transformer=MainTransformer(), postlex=MainIndenter())
main_parser = parser.parse

data_input = '''
print("HI");
x = input("Number: ");
'''
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_parser(data_input)
```

Output:

```
PRINTING HI
Number: qwe
```

If you want to enhance so the evaluation is all done afterwards then you need a class for every thing like `expr`, `add`, `mul`, etc. and a way of differentiating between a NUMBER and a variable, etc. What you're going to be doing is turning an arithmetic expression into a set of instructions which will return its result, hopefully also handling things like divide by 0, etc.

This should actually be relatively easy to construct in your Transformer - by returning the correct things from e.g add - which has to be given the val1 and val2 references to NUMBER/STRING/variable/class instance and return this Add(thing1,thing2).

I'd start by looking at the lark calc.py example because it already handles bracketed expressions - https://github.com/lark-parser/lark/blob/master/examples/calc.py - and based on this instead of performing every calculation immediately, you need to return class instances such that one single call to `.eval()` on the class instance of the whole expression `Expr()` evaluates all the contained class instances to return a single value.